# javascript - remove array element on condition

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I'd go about implementing a method in javascript that removes all elements of an array that clear a certain condition. (Preferably without using jQuery)

Ex.

```
ar = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
ar.removeIf( function(item, idx) {
    return item > 3;
});
```

The above would go through each item in the array and remove all those that `return true` for the condition (in the example, item > 3).

I'm just starting out in javascript and was wondering if anyone knew of a short efficient way to get this done.

--**update**--

It would also be great if the condition could work on object properties as well.

Ex.

```
ar = [ {num:1, str:"a"}, {num:2, str:"b"}, {num:3, str:"c"} ];
ar.removeIf( function(item, idx) {
    return item.str == "c";
});
```

Where the item would be removed if `item.str == "c"`

--**update2**--

It would be nice if index conditions could work as well.

Ex.

```
ar = [ {num:1, str:"a"}, {num:2, str:"b"}, {num:3, str:"c"} ];
ar.removeIf( function(item, idx) {
    return idx == 2;
});
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could add your own method to `Array` that does something similar, if `filter` does not work for you.

```
Array.prototype.removeIf = function(callback) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < this.length) {
        if (callback(this[i], i)) {
            this.splice(i, 1);
        }
        else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
};
```

To me, that's one of the coolest features of JavaScript.  Ian pointed out a more efficient way to do the same thing. Considering that it's JavaScript, every bit helps:

```
Array.prototype.removeIf = function(callback) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (callback(this[i], i)) {
            this.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

This avoids the need to even worry about the updating `length` or catching the next item, as you work your way left rather than right.

Comment: Thanks, works great. I like how this takes into consideration the index changes through splicing during iteration.

Comment: That's a little messy. Try http://jsfiddle.net/n8JEy/4/ - and you didn't pass `i` to the callback as the second param

Comment: @Ian I tend to prefer readability, but your solution is certainly more efficient. I also added the index as the second parameter (simply ignored it originally as it was not used, and I assumed that he didn't need it).

Comment: @dk123 As a newcomer to JavaScript, you are free to control the parameters of such callbacks as you see fit, and you can add whatever you want to them so long as the information is available (e.g., you could add the current array's length using `this.length` as a third parameter, if you had some inclination).

Comment: @pickypg No problem! That's definitely true. I guess I just didn't see a reason to separate the logic that way, but it's clearly fine to. And "messy" was the wrong term to use. Didn't realize about the second parameter, just wanted to point it out though :)

Comment: Mutating prototype of a predefined class is risky. Should be done only in polyfill-ish fashion, i. e. to add members which are already declared in specs but not implemented by browsers yet. Thanks for the solution, I'm using it as a local function.

Comment: Just to add some things to consider. Lodash's approach is quite good. It loops through the array "fowards". (most people would expect to look through the array in that direction)
And then once it captures the index of the items to remove, it removes them in reverse like above.

Answer (score 185):

You can use [Array filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

The code would look like this:

```js
ar = [1, 2, 3, 4];
ar = ar.filter(item => !(item > 3));
console.log(ar) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: If you translate `!(item > 3)` into human language, it will be `item <= 3`.

Comment: Keep in mind that Array.filter method creates a new array. If you reference your array in another variable, the reference will be broken afterwards:

    `ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    ar2 = ar1; 
    ar1 = ar1.filter(item => !(item > 3));
    console.log(ar1);
    console.log(ar2);`

Comment: @Miha_x64 In JavaScript, `!(item > 3)` isn't exactly the same as `item <= 3`. If that array contains `undefined` items, `!(item > 3)` will be true while `item <= 3` will be false.

Comment: This doesn't remove items from the array. This produces a new array and assigns to the `ar` variable. If any other variables have referenced the initial array in `ar`, they are not updated/affected. I would not consider this answer

Answer (score 47):

You can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which does the opposite:

```
ar.filter(function(item, idx) {
    return item <= 3;
});
```

Comment: As a head's up that is not supported in IE8 or below. You should also either negate the original expression, or it should be `<=`.

Comment: Doesn't Array.filter() return a new array with the filtered elements? Is there something that just removes the elements from the array?

Comment: @dk123: There's nothing pre-made. You'll have to write a `for` loop.,

Comment: Making a new array with `Array.filter` will likely be faster than manually splicing out of the given array.

Comment: @Blender That's very interesting. I swear I just looked into something recently comparing the two and it was the opposite. Stupid comment of mine deleted. Thanks for providing that for proof :)

Comment: @Ian: I only tested Chrome, so you may very well be right for other browsers.

Comment: @Blender No no, I'm sure this is right. I think I tested on Chrome before too. I do want to dive into this more though, maybe with bigger arrays and stuff too :)

Comment: @Ian: Looks like `.filter()` is faster than `.splice()` in every browser that I have.

Comment: @Blender I have no doubt that's true, I'm more concerned about the difference between the `push` scheme (and returning a new array) or the `splice` scheme

Answer (score 10):

Make it a one-liner with arrow function:

```
ar = ar.filter(i => i > 3);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [**lodash.remove**](https://lodash.com/docs#remove)

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var evens = _.remove(array, function(n) {
  return n % 2 == 0;
});

console.log(array);
// => [1, 3]

console.log(evens);
// => [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

if you need to remove exactly one item, and you know for sure that the item exists, you can use splice:

```
ar.splice(ar.findIndex(el => el.id === ID_TO_REMOVE), 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oriadam/72kgprw5/

Warning the above fails when item is not found, so use it when you already checked it is there for some reason.

EDIT: `filter` works, but in some cases you may prefer to use splice. [it is ~10 times faster than filter](https://jsfiddle.net/oriadam/tqu9c470/1/) and changes the array in situ.

For example, when you need to work with the item before removing it:

```
let foundIdx=arr.findIndex(x=>x.id=123);
if (foundIdx>=0) {
    const found=arr[foundIdx];
    /* ...do things with found item... */
    arr.splice(foundIdx,1); 
}
```

Comment: splice() + findIndex() isn't faster than just filter() 'ing out the removed values. Or is it in some cases?

Comment: @SaturnK yeah it's faster. created a simple benchmark removing 1000 items, filter took 7500ms and splice took 500ms, that's huge. here: https://jsfiddle.net/oriadam/tqu9c470/1/

Answer (score 5):

simply write the following example if condition could work on object properties as well

```
var ar = [ {num:1, str:"a"}, {num:2, str:"b"}, {num:3, str:"c"} ];
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0, len = ar.length; i<len; i++) {
        if (ar[i].str == "b") 
        {newArray.push(ar[i]);};
 };
console.log(newArray);
```

See the example [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishnamannem/ur9fvLLr/)

Answer (score 4):

My solution for an array of numbers would be:

```
ar = ar.filter(item => item < 4);
```

Comment: Best answer here, simple and elegant

Comment: @Marcel, it is a good answer if you don't mind losing the reference to the original array, as per this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995963/javascript-remove-array-element-on-condition#comment107002194_15995992

The question has no reassignment, implying a solution that manipulates the original array is what is requested.

Answer (score 3):

I love these kinds of questions and just a different version from me too... :)

```
Array.prototype.removeIf = function(expression) {
   var res = [];
    for(var idx=0; idx<this.length; idx++)
    {
      var currentItem = this[idx];
        if(!expression(currentItem))
        {
            res.push(currentItem);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

ar = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
var result = ar.removeIf(expCallBack);


console.log(result);
function expCallBack(item)
{
    return item > 3;
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps modify(or add another method) your code a bit to actually remove elements instead of returning a new array? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: whoever downvoted this so wrong. this is the best perfoming answer out of all of them. check the test by @Blender   jsperf.com/splice-vs-filter. it's at least 2x faster and as much as 15x faster in the latest versions of Firefox

Answer (score 1):

**Incorrect way**

First of all, any answer that suggests to use `filter` does not actually remove the item. Here is a quick test:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 2, 3];
numbers.filter(x => x === 2);
console.log(numbers.length);
```

In the above, the `numbers` array will stay intact (nothing will be removed). The `filter` method returns a new array with all the elements that satisfy the condition `x === 2` but the original array is left intact.

Sure you can do this:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 2, 3];
numbers = numbers.filter(x => x === 2);
console.log(numbers.length);
```

But that is simply assigning a new array to `numbers`.

---

**Correct way to remove items from array**

One of the correct ways, there are more than 1, is to do it as following. Please keep in mind, the example here intentionally has duplicated items so the removal of duplicates can be taken into consideration.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 2, 3];

// Find all items you wish to remove
// If array has objects, then change condition to x.someProperty === someValue
var numbersToRemove = numbers.filter(x => x === 2);

// Now remove them
numbersToRemove.forEach(x => numbers.splice(numbers.findIndex(n => n === x), 1));

// Now check (this is obviously just to test)
console.log(numbers.length);
console.log(numbers);
```

Now you will notice `length` returns 2 indicating only numbers 1 and 3 are remaining in the array.

Answer (score 0):

For the in-place remove, my solution is

```
ar.filter(item => !(item > 3))
  .forEach(obsoleteItem => ar.splice(ar.indexOf(obsoleteItem), 1));
```