# Removing items from javascript array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this array of objects:

```
$scope.frequencies = [{Id:124,clientId:3,name:'qqq'}, 
                      {Id:589,clientId:1,name:'www'}, 
                      {Id:45,clientId:3, name:'eee'},
                      {Id:567,clientId:1,name:'rrr'},
                      {Id:45,clientId:3,name:'eee'},
                      {Id:567,clientId:7,name:'rrr'}]
```

I need to remove all items from array above except where clientId = 3.

How can I implement it?

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - remove array element on condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995963/javascript-remove-array-element-on-condition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't remove but re-assign with

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.frequencies = [{Id:124,clientId:3,name:'qqq'}, 
                      {Id:589,clientId:1,name:'www'}, 
                      {Id:45,clientId:3, name:'eee'},
                      {Id:567,clientId:1,name:'rrr'},
                      {Id:45,clientId:3,name:'eee'},
                      {Id:567,clientId:7,name:'rrr'}];

$scope.frequencies = $scope.frequencies.filter(item => item.clientId === 3);

console.log($scope.frequencies);
```

Comment: Please, you should let OP share his effort. Its a very common issue and you should not answer such question.

Comment: `Array#splice` for in-place changes - just sayin, because you can't always re-assign an array without unwanted side effects

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this code snippet:

```
 $scope.frequencies = $scope.frequencies.filter((item)=> item.Id!=3);
```

Comment: Why are you using `.splice()`? What is the `a` in `a.length`?

Comment: It was by mistake, I edit that, instead of a.length it's $scope.frequencies.length

Comment: OK, so that brings me back to "Why are you using `.splice()`? It's redundant, because with params `(0, $scope.frequencies.length)` its *return* value will be all of the items from the array produced by `.filter()`, so you'd get the same result without it...

Comment: Yes, you are right it's redundant,there is no need to splice. We can simply assign the filters value to $scope.frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

In lodash, you could use [`_.remove(array, [predicate=_.identity])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#remove).

> Removes all elements from `array` that `predicate` returns truthy for and returns an array of the removed elements. The predicate is invoked with three arguments: *(value, index, array)*.

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.frequencies = [{ Id: 124, clientId: 3, name: 'qqq' }, { Id: 589, clientId: 1, name: 'www' }, { Id: 45, clientId: 3, name: 'eee' }, { Id: 567, clientId: 1, name: 'rrr' }, { Id: 45, clientId: 3, name: 'eee' }, { Id: 567, clientId: 7, name: 'rrr' }];

_.remove($scope.frequencies, a => a.clientId !== 3);

console.log($scope.frequencies);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter method which based on a comparison it returns an array of elements that meet the filter. On ES5:

```
$scope.frequencies.filter(function(element){
   return element.clientId == 3; 
})
```

On newer, ES6:

```
$scope.frequencies.filter( element => element.clientId != 3)
```

Check filter documentation: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)