# Javascript: destructive array.filter()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Is there a good functional style way of deleting elements in a JS array while looping?

I know filter can be used to create a new array:

```
var newArr = arr.filter((x) => x.foo > bar)
```

But is there a way to actually delete the elements from `arr` as you go?

BTW: I can't reassign, this is a data object on Vue component, so I need to update, not reassign.

BTW2: This is not a duplicate.  I know how to do it with normal JS iteration. I am looking for a functional way, and the referenced answer doesn't contain that.  Not a dupe.

Comment: `arr = arr.filter((x) => x.foo > bar)` ??

Comment: @Chiller that still creates a new array.

Comment: The only way I know of deleting items is looping backwards over the array, or using reduce to create a new array.

Comment: Is this because of concerns about memory consumption?

Comment: Could use `Array#reduceRight` to mutate original `arr.reduceRight((_,c,i)=> c.foo <= bar && arr.splice(i,1) )`

Comment: @Aominè not a duplicate.  please read the question completely.

Comment: @charlietfl not a dupe.  please read question completely.

Comment: @mtyson I have this same question.. did you figure out a solution as elegant as what you'd probably hoped for?

Comment: const x = [1,2,3,4,5];
x.forEach((item, i) => { if(item % 2 == 0) { x.splice(i, 1); }});
// x now contains [1,3,5]

Comment: Alternatively: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71955606/1564493

Answer (score 5):

Simply re-assign the `Array`

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr = arr.filter(v => v < 3);
console.log(arr);
```

If you can't re-assign, use a loop and `Array.splice`. Note that for every deleted item, the index should be decremented by 1.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
  if (arr[i] < 3) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    // you should decrement the index (i) now
    i -= 1;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I can't reassign, this is a data object on  Vue component, so I need to update, not reassign.

Comment: This does not the answer of doing the filtering without re-assiging to the variable.

Comment: @fstamour now it does.

Comment: @KooiInc thanks :P   (I made a small edit let -> const)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do this

```
arr = arr.filter((x) => x.foo > bar)
```

UPDATE:

We can splice the unwanted item from the array while iterating, if you do not want to re-assign.
Does this answer your question?

```js
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].x > bar) arr.splice(idx, 1);
}
```

Comment: This does not the answer of doing the filtering without re-assiging to the variable.