# Remove element from Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array of arrays like the following:

```
myArray = [
  ["ooooh", "that"],
  ["dog ", "of"],
  ["mine", "word...."]
]
```

I now wish to delete the array item: `["ooooh", "that"]`

Assuming that I know element 0 is `"ooooh"` and element 1 is `"that"`, but **i do not know the element's position within the enclosing array**, can this be achieved efficiently?

The general responses from my research seem to be saying `delete myArray['1']`, or know the number of the element in the array- in my case in need both element 0 & 1 to match for removal.

In pseudo code i would like:

```
myArray.destroy(["ooooh", "that"])
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `myList.splice(myList.findIndex(e => e[0] === "ooooh" && e[1] === "that"), 1);`

Comment: Can you assume that your delete array will be identical to the one being deleted?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*without looping*"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - remove array element on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995963/javascript-remove-array-element-on-condition)

Comment: @PM77-1 I meant without explicitly writing a loop myself, thanks for the clarification

Comment: All clever boys copy pasting filter solutions from existing answered questions, shameful. I'd recommend having a map like structure, have hash value of each inner array as the key of the index in the greater array, & use that to delete from the greater array. Having an array or array is just impractical

Comment: @User632716, check my answer. You can specifically use `myList.destroy(["ooooh", "that"])` to remove elements.

Comment: A note towards my comment: if there is the possibility the element does not exist, you need to add additional code. `findIndex` will return `-1` if it does not exist, and `splice` will interpret that as `splice(myList.length - 1, 1)`.

Comment: Just for the sake of learning...
Also solutions like splice() or findIndex() are implicitly looping, right?

Comment: @Pitto if you tag PM 77-1 you might get a response from him (seems like he knows the answer )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `splice` to remove an item out of the list.

```
myList.splice(
   myList.findIndex( item => 
     item[0] == "ooooh" && item[1] == "that"
   ), 
1);
```

Hope this helps :>

```js
myList = [
["ooooh", "that"],
["dog ", "of"],
["mine", "word...."]];

myList.splice(myList.findIndex(item => item[0] == "ooooh" && item[1] == "that"), 1);

console.log(myList)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well there are several ways of doing this as the other answers pointed out, but I think the simplest way is to use filter. Like this::

```js
myList = [
    ["ooooh", "that"],
    ["dog ", "of"],
    ["mine", "word"]
];
    
myList = myList.filter((element)=>
    //filter condition 
    (!
       ((element[0] == 'ooooh') && (element[1] == 'that'))
    )
);

console.log(myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter your array

```js
var myList = [
["ooooh", "that"],
["dog ", "of"],
["mine", "word...."]
]

deleteFromList = (val, list) => list.filter(a=>JSON.stringify(a)!=JSON.stringify(val))

console.log(
  deleteFromList(["ooooh", "that"], myList)
)

/* Same as */

myList = myList.filter(a=>JSON.stringify(a)!=JSON.stringify(["ooooh", "that"]))

console.log(myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function comparing arrays as strings

```js
myList = [
  ["ooooh", "that"],
  ["dog ", "of"],
  ["mine", "word...."]
];

let findMe = ["ooooh", "that"]

myList = myList.filter((curr) => curr.join() !== findMe.join())

console.log(myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter and every together to have it flexible.

```js
const myList = [
  ["ooooh", "that"],
  ["dog ", "of"],
  ["mine", "word...."]
];

const toDelete = ["ooooh", "that"];

const res = myList.filter(e => ! toDelete.every(x => e.includes(x)));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pop` to remove an item out of your array.
[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)'s its documentation.

```js
myArray = [
["ooooh", "that"],
["dog ", "of"],
["mine", "word..."]
]

console.log("Original Array:");
console.log(myArray);

/**
 * Removes one array from an array of arrays 
 *
 * @param  {String} myArray       - The original array of arrays
 * @param  {String} arrayToRemove - The array that will be removed from myArray
 */
function destroy(myArray, arrayToRemove) {
        arrayIndexToBeRemoved = myArray.findIndex(item => item[0] == arrayToRemove[0] && item[1] == arrayToRemove[1]);
        if (arrayIndexToBeRemoved != -1){
            removedArray = myArray.pop(arrayIndexToBeRemoved);
            console.log("Removed: " + removedArray);
        } else {
            console.log("Couldn't find: " + arrayToRemove + " in: " + myArray);
        }
}

destroy(myArray, ["mine", "word..."]);

console.log("Final Array:");
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: thanks for the response, and i'm not the downvoter, but this needs to be for a list of lists, and pop would show the last element pushed to the list no?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but here is my input:

---

```js
let myList = [
  ["ooooh", "that"],
  ["dog ", "of"],
  ["mine", "word...."]
];

Array.prototype.destroy = function(array) {
  this.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (JSON.stringify(el) === JSON.stringify(array)) {
      this.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
}

console.log(myList);

myList.destroy(["ooooh", "that"]);

console.log(myList);
```