# Identifying non-matches in two javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have a set of file paths in an array called `directories`. I have a set of files in an array called `articles`.

I am trying to edit the `directories` array by reading each file in `articles` and then removing the item from `directories` if there's a match (the files contain file paths, and I am isolating ones that are not used).

This should then produce a final `directories` array containing all non-matches.

At the moment the `directories` array reduces from 203 to 85, but some items in the array exist in the files. I am not sure what is at issue in the logic I have here:

```
for (let w = 0; w < articles.length; w++) {
  const data = fs.readFileSync(articles[w]);
  for (let y = 0; y < directories.length; y++) {
    const index = directories.indexOf(directories[y]);
    if (data.includes(directories[y])) {
      directories.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

I know there are packages out there that do similar but they don't work for my specific use, and I have some extra functionality I want to build on top of this.

But is `fs.readFile` unreliable itself?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using the synchronous version of `.readFile()`? Get the paths of all files (`.readFile()` + `Promise.all()` + `.map()`) and then use `.filter()` to get a list of "non-matching" directories.

Comment: When you use splice, the array size shrinks by one, and the current index `y` points to the "next item" instead of the current item.  When your for loop increments y, you have skipped that "next item".

Comment: Why `.readFile()` at all? You can get the path of a file with `.dirname()` from the `path` package

Comment: Does this answer your question: [javascript - remove array element on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995963/javascript-remove-array-element-on-condition)?