# Breaking a while loop with a ternary operator (one line if else)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

i would like to break a while loop with inside ternary operator.

Example:

```
while (true){ onderwerpenArray.includes(temp) ? onderwerpenArray.splice(onderwerpenArray.indexOf(temp), 1) : break;}
```

But i get a message saying expresion expected

I would like to know if this is possible and how.
otherwise if you know a different way to make it as compact as this i would like to know as well.

Comment: "Compact" is not the measure of good code.

Comment: It looks like this is doing: `onderwerpenArray = onderwerpenArray.filter(item => item !== temp);`  It's also a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15995963/1563833

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`break` is not an expression so it cannot be used in that context. However, you can directly put `onderwerpenArray.includes(temp)` in the loop condition:

```js
while (onderwerpenArray.includes(temp)) 
    onderwerpenArray.splice(onderwerpenArray.indexOf(temp), 1);
```

To remove all occurrences of `temp` in `onderwerpenArray`, it is simpler to use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
onderwerpenArray = onderwerpenArray.filter(x => x !== temp);
```